# jQuery fadeOut/fadeIn effect help. (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I have a basic script running to create a slider effect. I have it setup to simply switch elements. Instead of just switching, im looking to create a fadeOut/fadeIn effect. The documentation ive been finding seems to be different with each script... is there a basic or beginner level method to adding in a fade effect to a pre-existing script? Thank you in advance.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/williamwong/865gG/1/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use jquery's [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods.

```
$('div').fadeIn();
```

The documentation for these methods([fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)) has great examples.

**EDIT**

Here's how I would alter your code to make use of it:

```
var cycle = window.setInterval(next, 2000);

function next() {
    $('#slides .current').fadeOut(function(el) {
        $(this).removeClass('current').next().add('#slides :first').last().addClass('current').fadeIn()
        });
}
```

Basically, you want to wait until fadeOut is complete to fade in the next item. Other than that, your code is pretty much the same.

Updated fork of your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9BQTH/2/

Comment: Hello Kekoa, Thank you for your recommendation. I followed the script you put on here (the fiddle didnt match it and wasnt working entirely correct) and the script, for the most part, is working nicely. The only question i have, is how can i avoid causing the page to reposition after the cycle completes and why does it require to go through the entire cycle once before the fadeIn effect works? Have you ever seen anything like this before? here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/williamwong/9BQTH/4/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you could use the animate(), hide(), show() functions using opacity property.